# How do I make iTunes 'forget' a device in Mavericks?

Tags: itunes, ios, macos, icloud

Before Mavericks it seems it was easy to make iTunes forget a device as per this question: [Can you make iTunes forget a device?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62928/can-you-make-itunes-forget-a-device)

However according to [this Apple support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1865) Sync Services doesn't exist anymore in Mavericks

> Note: OS X Mavericks does not use Sync Services. Instead, Mavericks supports sharing your information using several network-based and cloud-based solutions. If you want to sync your information across multiple devices and computers, you should use one or more of these methods. These include iCloud, CardDAV servers, CalDAV servers, or servers that use the Exchange ActiveSync protocol.

What is the new trick in Mavericks to make iTunes forget a device?

Comment: By "forgetting" you mean what exactly? Not having the iDevice show up in the sync drop down at top right?

Comment: @patrix I want it to forget what songs and apps I wanted it to sync before.

Comment: Looks like maybe sync services is coming back soon? http://www.macrumors.com/2014/03/18/itunes-beta-local-syncing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It is not possible in Mavericks

At least 10.9.3 and down. Recently Apple brought back Sync Services in 10.9.3 however the resetsync.pl script is not in the Sync Services framework folder. Seeing how Apple brought back Sync Services without the script it seems unlikely that the script and reset functionality will return.

Answer (score 0):

**iDevices are not linked to iTunes, but to a certain `iTunes library`.**

The only thing iTunes remembers are device backups. These can be deleted from the `iTunes preferences`. So in oder to 'forget' a device, you can restore the device and sync it to another library, or create a new iTunes library.

EDIT: Solution

Go to settings > General > usage > Music, then swipe the text saying "all music" to the right in order to make the red 'delete' button appear. Tap this in order to remove all music of your device. Then connect to iTunes and sync. iTunes should now re-sync all of your music to your device solving the problem you have. (tracks being skipped)

Comment: I deleted the backups but it use still wants to sync certain songs with my device. I want my device to appear as new to itunes.

Comment: Then just restore the device using the restore button in the general tab, select the data from your library which you would like to sync and then itunes will recognise your device as new.

Comment: I don't want to have to change anything on my device just to fix my music sync issue. Plus I want to keep my backup with iCloud not iTunes.

Comment: If you just want to fix music sync issues you can uncheck the box which says: sync music. Then sync so all music will be removed from your device, then recheck the checkbox, select the music you want to sync, and you are done.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that and Music.app shows all the songs I wanted to sync but when I tap on any of them it skips to the song and music never plays. I want to start fresh and I could before Sync Services was removed.

Comment: Take a look at the edit i made, hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I still have issues with apps. When I start syncing it wants to sync a bunch of old apps I've deleted before.