# iTunes remembers my friend's iPhone from when he plugged it in to recharge

Tags: iphone, itunes, macos, wifi, data-synchronization

Every time my friend's iPhone is on the same WiFi network, iTunes asks me if I want to update his phone's OS and then later asks if I want to update his carrier profile or something like that. How can I keep this from happening?

I'm on Mavericks, and [this previous question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62928/can-you-make-itunes-forget-a-device?lq=1) doesn't help and [this Mavericks specific question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107118/how-do-i-make-itunes-forget-a-device-in-mavericks) seems to be asking for something different.

His device does not appear in `iTunes > Preferences > Devices`, but does show up in `File > Devices` (even when he isn't on the same WiFi network)

**New Information:**
It seems like his device appearing in `File > Devices` was just because that menu keeps the last device connected around. Now that my phone has connected it is the only device in that menu.

Comment: Is his account logged in the iTunes store?

Comment: @Robuust no, it's my account still

Answer (score -1):

Make sure 'Sync with this device over WIFI' in the summary tab is not selected.

Comment: "Even when isn't on the same wifi network", thus impossible

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: His device shows up in File>Devices even when not on the same WIFI network, which is normal behavior.  Thus you misread the issue.